# How to select a cell to copy its content (using ctrl+c for example) along with row selection enabled in Primefaces 5 datatable?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Well the example is Primefaces Datatable row selection showcase.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Selecting a cell to copy it's content is not possible because mouse keyup unselect the cell. So Ctrl+c is possible during mouse keydown only. I am still trying to find a way around.  Would appreciate any light on this.

Answer (score 0):

It does not resolve this issue completely but you can try setting `disabledTextSelection` to false.

**Update**

You can select text on cell now. However, text will be also selected while using Shift or Ctrl key to select rows. That's reason why I said that this solution doesn't resolve the issue "completely"

Comment: What does it not resolve and what does it resolve? Please improve the answer

Comment: Sorry for any unclear things. I have updated my answer.